# How can I achieve all bonuses for transfer in Bravely Default 3DS Demo?

Tags: bravely-default, bravely-default-demo

So when I first started the demo, it stated that I could gain up to 7 total bonuses to transfer to the full version when it comes out.

How do I go about building and getting bonuses? Is it clearing the dungeons in the game? How much I level up my team? How many quests I finish?

What are these bonuses, and in what way can I gain all the bonuses to transfer to the full version?

Comment: I have 6 of the 7 so I will not answer yet, but I can tell you that achieving maximum levels and mastering all jobs does **not** grant one of these bonuses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full set of bonuses are:

- **Gameplay reward**

  - **Played demo version: Caldisian Relief Set**
  - `Antidote` × 2
  - `Eye Drops` × 2
  - `Echo Herbs` × 2
  - **Norende fully restored: Caldislan Adventurer's Set**
  - `Bronze Bangle` × 1
  - `Pheonix Down` × 2
- **Mid-boss reward**

  - **Melusine reward: Caldislan Recovery Set**
  - `Potion` × 3
  - `Hi-Potion` × 1
  - **Minotaur reward: Caldislan White Mage Set**
  - `Staff` × 1
  - `Ether` × 1
  - **Adamantite Shell reward: Caldislan Black Mage's Set**
  - `Rod` × 1
  - `Ether` × 1
- **Boss Reward**

  - **Dragon reward: Caldislan Soldier's Set**
  - `Bronze Helm` × 1
  - `Leather Armor` × 1
  - **Automaton reward: Caldislan Knight Set**
  - `Broadsword` × 1
  - `Buckler` × 1

You can ask the soldier to the west of the Inn during the day which bonuses you earned are. He will tell you if you have them all at the end of his dialogue tree.

And finally, up to 20 villagers from Norende will follow you into the main game.

Bonus transfers will work for all save files in the main game. My sister and I were both able to take advantage of the bonuses I unlocked from the demo.

Answer (score 2):

You get one bonus for starting the demo,

One bonus for each boss you defeat (demon, turtle, minotaur, dragon, construct)

and one final bonus for finishing restoration of the town.

Also, you can transfer up to 20 villagers you collect from the town to the main game.